# Dates are not sorted in correct order on website?

Tags: python, jquery, django, datetime, datatables

I am using this https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html for HTML tables as it provides multiple features.
My Django website passes on dates as strings to the frontend **Collection Date** in descending order

[image]

and also datetime object to display on frontend HTML template.

[image]

But it is not sorted correctly.
This website has inbuilt sort facility which is not working fine.
https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html
How to sort date string with format "%m-%d-%Y"?
Please help me to resolve this.
Thank you

Comment: The dates in screenshots attached seems sorted properly. Am I missing something?

Comment: @AngrejKumar Keep a closer look , first ss shows descending order of dates but 2019 is coming on top.

Comment: Its sorted in order but its sorted as per angle icon show on column, right?

Comment: There are various questions & answers on this site relating to dates - and how to sort them - in DataTables. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdatatables%5D+date+sort) for a list of some of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be great if you can post your code as well. But anyways, will recommend one blind fix.
[Article](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/)
So here you need to mention explicitly on the basis of what you want to sort column. In your case following will be a useful selection.

1. monthYear
2. date-de
3. date-uk
4. date-euro
5. date-eu
6. date-dd-MMM-yyyy

You can choose accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @Sumit that article helped a lot.